# Get data from postgres query in express.js

Tags: javascript, express

```
app.get('/some_endpoint', function (req, res) {

    function getData() {
        pool.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $1', [40], (error, res) => {
            if (error) {
                throw error
            }
            console.log(res.rows[0]); // this logs the correct output
            return res.rows[0];
        });
    }

    let data = getData(); 
    console.log(data);      // this logs undefined
});
```

I can't get `data` from the query, for some reason it is undefined sometimes, and sometimes it is not ---0\_/0\_/0---

Comment: This will answer your question: [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Bergi no, I don't care if it is async or not, thanks anyway

Comment: Well you should, because it *is* asynchronous. And `data` isn't "*sometimes*" `undefined`, it *always* is.

Comment: Your `return res.rows[0]` is returning from the `pool.query()` callback, NOT from the `getData()` function.  In fact, because `pool.query()` is non-blocking and asynchronous, the `getData()` function returns BEFORE the `pool.query()` callback is even called.  It is impossible to return that value from `getData()`.  Instead, read the duplicate referenced by Bergi and see what your options are (hint: they are using a promise, callback or event or similar mechanism).  Or just put `res.send()` inside the `pool.query()` callback and just handle the data there and stop trying to return it.